# Connect to db and hiding elements with js

Tags: php, javascript, database

I want to check if the value true is present in a db and if present i want to hide a partcular id using javascript.

I know both parts - how to check database and hide elements with js.

the question is - how do i integrate both parts?

Ex - Check if in table "Tutorials", the value "true" is present or not. If yes, document.getelementbyid(box).style.display :none;

How do i integrate both? thanks.

Comment: AJAX , google it there are tons and tons of tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest your php within your javascript call. The PHP will get processed at the server side, and will return a boolean, then use that to be part of an if block to decide what to hide

```
if (<?php Check database and return boolean ?>){
    $('#box').hide();
}
```

Comment: I don't see why.  The db query has to be made somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so through [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp). From your page, you send a request to server-side language whose return value can be used in your condition.

For example, here is sample code with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'your_file.php'
  success:function(response){
    if (response == 'true'){
      $('#box').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

And from your server-side script, you get the value of required field from database and if it exists, you output `'true'` from it.

If you don't want to use jQuery and go with vanilla javascript, you can check out this tutorial for ajax:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: okay..in php then, what should i do after i query the db? Thanks

Comment: @sarthak: Whatever output you send from your server-side script, compare it later. For example if you output `test`, you will have to compare it with `test` like `if (response == 'test'){//hide}`

Comment: thnks...is this method more faster or the one mentioned above?

Comment: there is slight difference but if you use `GET` as method/type of request in ajax, it will be little faster.